# Windows Time change causes TcpClient timed out

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-7-x64

In our c# application, we are using a TcpClient listening for messages coming from our clients.

When the connection is established we set a time out on the socket, to avoid to have useless open connections.

We encountered a strange behaviour when we change the Windows Time to a future time.

Just to be clear.

Socket Timeout set to 30seconds.

Starting situation: Windows Time = 10:00:00 (UTC)

We manually change time to 10:01:00(UTC)

Immediately we got the Socket timedout.

Is this a normal behaviour in Windows or something bad is happening in our implementation?

System references:
Windows 7 x64
.Net 4.5

Edit:
We set the TimeOut in this way:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpConnectionListener.AcceptTcpClient(); 
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = RECEIVE_TIMEOUT;
```

We expected that internally the TcpClient was using a Timer or something like that and not using the Windows Clock. Is this right?

Comment: Why is that strange? You have set the current time past the timeout setting, so the socket times out.

Comment: Indeed.  This is expected (although not bumped into on a day to day basis by normal circumstances) behavior.  The application is looking at the time when the connection is established, and then looks at the time again after the time change.  It sees that the 30 seconds have passed according to the system's time, and the connection is dropped.

Comment: You can see [the source for TcpClient](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs)

Comment: The thought was that the timeout would be independent of windows time as in some internal ticker to verify if the timeout has occurred.